# What's the benefit of using reactive programming over ExecutorService?

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice, project-reactor, reactor

If both are asynchronous in nature, then what's the use of using Reactive programming over ExecutorService in Java? In what ways reactive programming can be found effective as compared to ExecutorService?

Comment: Finding it hard to compare *Reactive programming* with *ExecutorService*. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: `Reactive programming` is a type of declarative programming paradigm. `ExecutorService` is a class in a class-oriented programming language. As ernest_k said, it's like comparing apples and cars.

Comment: isn't reactive programming based (could be based) on _some_ type of executor under the hood?

Comment: Maybe he's trying to compare reactive programming to asynchronous programming?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/executor-framework-in-java-take-control-over-your-1

Comment: @ernest_k I mean to say using Executor Service we can be able to serve multiple request using a single thread or least number number thread by reusing it. Reactor is also doing the same thing i.e. it serves multiple request using single or least no. of threads. Then what's the purpose of using reactive programming over executor service framework.

Comment: @Eugene yes that's what I am trying to say. please see my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asynchronous programming usually includes some kinds of task interaction. Different kinds of asynchronous programming provide different kinds of task interaction.

ExecutorService executes submitted tasks as soon as there exists available processor, that is, it provides only simplest form of asynchronous programming, without task interaction at all.

Reactive programming provides channels to exchange messages with backpressure, which is quite advanced kind of task interaction. But under the hood, it still uses an ExecutorService.